# Can "board wipes" kill creatures with protection?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can [Crux of Fate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrux%20of%20Fate%5d) kill a creature with protection from black? My friend says it can't because protection gives it complete defense from black.